# How to determine what characters these are being stored in the Oracle Database so I can properly configure my Putty session?

Tags: oracle, utf-8, multibyte

Using Oracle and within SQL*Plus I execute a SQL command using the DUMP function.

```
SQL> select DUMP(Field1, 16) from MY_TABLE;
```

It prints out the following :

```
Typ=1 Len=10 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,83,e2,82,ac,c3,83,e2,82,ac
```

The SQL*Plus session is run within my Putty session and when the "**Remote character set :**" configuration is changed to various settings (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe), ....) , different characters appear.

Using UTF-8 conversion (assuming it is done correctly) with the above info it almost seems like it should be the same 2 characters.

```
c3         83
11000011   10000011
11000011
C3


e2        82        ac
11100010  10000010  10101100
10000010101100
20AC
```

How can I tell exactly what characters (whether it is 1,2 or more characters) it should be then I know that my Putty session is configured correctly?

Comment: `c3,83` is **Ã** (U+00C3) and `e2,82,ac` is **€** (U+20AC) as per UTF-8, so your text should be `Ã€Ã€`, 4 letters encoded in 10 bytes. Is that what you wanted to know? ([list of UTF-8 versus Unicode codepoints](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl))

Comment: Actually I was more interested in how to calculate which to use. Is it because Oracle is showing UTF-8 that you know to convert to Unicode to to find the appropriate values?  How would you know if you shouldn't just use the original hex values E2, 82, ac as 3 individual characters instead of 20AC for just 1 ?

Comment: You cannot "calculate" - you need to declare: if it wouldn't be Oracle's `CharacterSet=AL32UTF8` where I read it is `UTF-8` it would then be my experience and/or heuristics where it is **most likely** UTF-8 (after a while you know which bytes mean what and there are patterns and bytes which must never occur). Have a read on text encodings - if it doesn't come with a declaration ("_I am ISO-8859-2_") you have no clue which byte(s) map to which characters.